Evaluate the integral $ I = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{\text{sinc}(f) e^{j\pi f}}{1+2j\pi f} df $
Evaluate the integral $ I = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{\text{sinc}(f) e^{i\pi f}}{1+2i\pi f} df $.
I have solved this problem as detailed below and am seeking potentially better solutions.

Your integral is
$$\begin{aligned}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \dfrac{\sin(f)e^{i\pi f}}{(1+2\pi i f)f}\,\mathrm df&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \dfrac{e^{i(\pi+1)f}-e^{i(\pi-1)f}}{2i(1+2\pi i f)f}\,\mathrm df\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \dfrac{e^{i(\pi+1)f}}{2i(1+2\pi i f)f}\,\mathrm df-\int_{-\infty}^\infty \dfrac{e^{i(\pi-1)f}}{2i(1+2\pi i f)f}\,\mathrm df
\end{aligned}$$
To compute these we'll help ourselves by defining
$$f(z)=\dfrac{e^{iaz}}{2i(1+2\pi i z)z}$$
and using the residue theorem.
Since $a>0$, we can use a sunset contour on the upper half plane, all while avoiding the pole at $z=0$. Therefore,
$$\oint_C f(z)\,\mathrm dz=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \dfrac{e^{iax}}{2i(1+2\pi i x)x}\,\mathrm dx+\int_\Gamma \dfrac{e^{iaz}}{2i(1+2\pi i z)z}\,\mathrm dz$$
The arc integral $\Gamma:\{\displaystyle\lim_{R\to\infty}z=Re^{i\theta},0\leq\theta\leq \pi\}$ can be shown to be $0$ applying the triangle inequality and then the limit as $R\to\infty$. Using the Residue Thm. we arrive at
$$I(a)\equiv \int_{-\infty}^\infty \dfrac{e^{iax}}{2i(1+2\pi i x)x}\,\mathrm dx=\pi i \,\text{Res}(f(z),0)+2\pi i\,\text{Res}\left(f(z),\dfrac{i}{2\pi }\right)$$
It is quite easy to compute the residue at $0$ and it is $\dfrac{1}{2i}$. Moreover, the residue at $z=\dfrac{i}{2\pi}$ is easy to calculate too and yields $-\dfrac{e^{-\frac{a}{2\pi}}}{2i}$. Substituting these results in the equation above gives
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \dfrac{e^{iax}}{2i(1+2\pi i x)x}\,\mathrm dx=\dfrac{\pi}{2}-\pi e^{-\frac{a}{2\pi}}$$
Thence, the original integral can be rewritten as
$$\small \color{blue}{\int_{-\infty}^\infty \dfrac{\text{sinc}(f)e^{i\pi f}}{(1+2\pi i f)}\,\mathrm df}=I(\pi+1)-I(\pi-1)=\pi\left(e^{\frac{-\pi+1}{2\pi}}-e^{\frac{-\pi-1}{2\pi}}\right)\color{blue}{=\dfrac{2\pi}{\sqrt e}\sinh\left(\dfrac{1}{2\pi}\right)}$$

$\mathbf{EDIT:}$ Looks like I messed up the definition of $\text{sinc}$ so the integral should've been
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \dfrac{\sin(\pi f)e^{i\pi f}}{(1+2\pi i f)\pi f}\,\mathrm df\overset{\pi f\to f}{=}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\dfrac{e^{i2f}}{2\pi if(1+2if)}\,\mathrm df-\int_{-\infty}^\infty\dfrac{1}{2\pi if(1+2if)}\,\mathrm df$$
This time we'll use the function
$$f(z)=\dfrac{e^{iaz}}{2\pi iz(1+2iz)}.$$
Applying yet again the same technique we get
$$I(a)\equiv\int_{-\infty}^\infty\dfrac{e^{iax}}{2\pi ix(1+2ix)}\,\mathrm dx=\dfrac{1}{2}-e^{-\frac{a}{2}}$$
Therefore,
$$\color{green}{\int_{-\infty}^\infty \dfrac{\sin(\pi f)e^{i\pi f}}{(1+2\pi i f)\pi f}\,\mathrm df}=I(2)-I(0)\color{green}{=1-\dfrac{1}{e}}$$

The OP is defining the sinc function as $\text{sinc}(x)=\frac{\sin(\pi x)}{\pi x}$.

First, consider the inverse Fourier transform of the function $\frac{\operatorname{sinc}(f)}{1+2i \pi f}=\frac{1}{1+2i \pi f} \cdot \frac{\sin \pi f}{\pi f} $. According to the properties of the convolution operator, the inverse Fourier transform of this product is given by:
\begin{equation}
   e^{-t} u(t) * \Pi(t)
\end{equation}
Where $u(t)$ is $0$ for $t<0$ and $1$ for $t>=0$ and  $\Pi(t)$ is equal to $1$ for $\frac{-1}{2}<t<\frac{1}{2}$ and is $0$ elsewhere.
This implies:
\begin{equation}
e^{-t} u(t) * \Pi(t)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{\operatorname{sinc}(f)}{1+2i \pi f} e^{2i \pi f t} d f
\end{equation}
Consequently, we have:
\begin{aligned}
& I=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{\operatorname{sinc}(f)}{1+2i \pi f} e^{i \pi f} d f=\left.e^{-t} u(t) * \prod(t)\right|_{t=\frac{1}{2}} \\ & \longrightarrow I=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{-\tau} u(\tau) \Pi(t-\tau) d \tau |_{t=\frac{1}{2}} \\
& \Rightarrow \quad \mathrm{I}=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{-\tau} u(\tau) \Pi\left(\frac{1}{2}-\tau\right) d \tau=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{-\tau} u(\tau) \Pi\left(\tau-\frac{1}{2}\right) d \tau=\int_0^1 e^{-\tau} d \tau=1-e^{-1}
\end{aligned}
Edit:
For completeness:

\begin{equation}
  \mathcal{F} \{e^{-t} u(t)\}=\frac{1}{1+2i \pi f},\\
  \mathcal{F} \{\Pi(t)\}= \frac{\sin (\pi f)}{\pi f}=sinc(f).
\end{equation}

Product in frequency domain is equal to convolution in time domain.



Mathematica indicates $$\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\text{sinc}(f), e^{i \pi  f}}{1+2 i \pi  f} , df=\frac{2 \pi \sinh\left(\frac{1}{2 \pi}\right)}{\sqrt{e}}\approx 0.609095$$ so it appears your result is incorrect.

The preceding result is equivalent to the inverse Fourier transform $$\mathcal{F}f^{-1}\left\frac{\text{sinc}(f)}{1+2 i \pi f}\right=\int\limits{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\text{sinc}(f)}{1+2 i \pi f}, e^{2 i \pi t f} , df=\frac{1}{2} \pi \left(2 e^{-t-\frac{1}{2 \pi}} \left(e^{1/\pi} \theta(2 \pi t-1)-\theta(2 \pi t+1)\right)+\text{sgn}(2 \pi t+1)+\text{sgn}(1-2 \pi  t)\right)$$ evaluated at $t=\frac{1}{2}$.

Since $$g(\tau)=\mathcal{F}_f^{-1}\text{sinc}(f)=\frac{\pi}{2} (\text{sgn}(2 \pi \tau+1)+\text{sgn}(1-2 \pi \tau))$$ and $$h(\tau)=\mathcal{F}f^{-1}\left\frac{1}{1+2 i \pi  f}\right=e^{-\tau}, \theta (\tau)$$ this is also equivalent to the convolution $$\leftg(\tau) * h(\tau)\right=\int\limits{-\infty}^{\infty} g(\tau) h(t-\tau) , d\tau$$ evaluated at $t=\frac{1}{2}$.

@StevenClark, it's possible that you and OP might be using different definitions of sinc function. In electrical engineering texts sinc is often defined as $\frac{\sin(\pi t)}{\pi t}$, whereas in traditional mathematics, the $\pi$ scaling is not used.

@Srini Thanks, apparently we are indeed using different definitions.
